# Tkinter multiple frames/'pages': using canvas images

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I would like to employ multiple frames in a GUI, where the page switches depending on the button clicked. I know that there's several threads already about this, and I've been looking at [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7546050/switch-between-two-frames-in-tkinter).
However, for my pages, I need different images on canvasses within each of my frames, so that when I raise a different frame, it comes with a new canvas and a new image on that canvas. I've tried a lot but I don't know how to get it to work so that the canvasses appear with their images.

Here's what I have so far, mostly copying from above link:

```
import tkinter as tk   # python3

TITLE_FONT = ("Helvetica", 18, "bold")

class SampleApp(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        # the container is where we'll stack a bunch of frames
        # on top of each other, then the one we want visible
        # will be raised above the others
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}
        self.frames["StartPage"] = StartPage(parent=container, controller=self)
        self.frames["PageOne"] = PageOne(parent=container, controller=self)
        self.frames["PageTwo"] = PageTwo(parent=container, controller=self)

        self.frames["StartPage"].grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.frames["PageOne"].grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.frames["PageTwo"].grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame("StartPage")

    def show_frame(self, page_name):
        '''Show a frame for the given page name'''
        frame = self.frames[page_name]
        frame.tkraise()


class StartPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller

        self._canvas = tk.Canvas(parent, bg='white', width=900, height=3517, scrollregion=(0, 2800, 100, 800))
        self._photo = tk.PhotoImage(file='images/homegraphic.gif')
        self._canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=self._photo, anchor='nw')

        label = tk.Label(self, text="This is the start page", font=TITLE_FONT)
        label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)

        button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Go to Page One",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame("PageOne"))
        button2 = tk.Button(self, text="Go to Page Two",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame("PageTwo"))
        button1.pack()
        button2.pack()


class PageOne(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        label = tk.Label(self, text="This is page 1", font=TITLE_FONT)
        label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)
        button = tk.Button(self, text="Go to the start page",
                           command=lambda: controller.show_frame("StartPage"))
        button.pack()


class PageTwo(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        label = tk.Label(self, text="This is page 2", font=TITLE_FONT)
        label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)
        button = tk.Button(self, text="Go to the start page",
                           command=lambda: controller.show_frame("StartPage"))
        button.pack()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = SampleApp()
    app.mainloop()
```

How do I get the canvas image to appear? I've spent a long time trying to figure this out and would appreciate any help!

Comment: forgot to add, when I do grid the canvas in class StartPage, the window pops up the right size but shows nothing, just the normal grey tkinter background with the text and buttons at the top.

Comment: Your canvas needs to use the current frame itself as master, not the parent, just like your Buttons do: `self._canvas = tk.Canvas(self, bg='white', width=900, height=3517, scrollregion=(0, 2800, 100, 800))`. And  then you need to use `pack` to lay out, since the StartPage is managed by pack.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
self._canvas = tk.Canvas(parent, ...)
```

Everything within a page needs to be a child of the page or one of its descendants.

It needs to be this:

```
self._canvas = tk.Canvas(self, ...)
```